# How to filter and sort MyHeritage DNA matches?

Tags: dna, myheritage.com

I'm relatively new to MyHeritage.  And I'm having a hard time figuring out how to manage all my DNA matches. (The help center-DNA maches shows no help and there appears to be no MyHeritage forum for questions or discussion).  I have over 2200 matches and it's growing!

1. The biggest problem I have is, that there appears to be no way to sort by "newest match first". Each time I want to discover my new matches I have to download the complete list.
2. I would also like to sort the list by "largest segment match first" (not largest total DNA) My ancestors are endogenous and the largest segment is not very useful for me (largest segment is not that useful either, but it gives me a different perspective.)  Again, the only way I can do this is to download the complete list of segment matches and do the above locally.
3. Finally, it would be nice if there was a feature to filter matches that have a greater segment match than X. (For instance, I would like to see all matches that have DNA segments greater than 30 cM.)

Anyone with tips on how the above can be done would be appreciated. (Or, if MyHeritage plans to implement these features in the future.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from your [MyHeritage DNA matches page](https://www.myheritage.com/dna/matches/), the results look something like this:

[image]

You can see the dropdown menu at the top which shows 5 ways to sort the results:

- Shared DNA
- Shared segments
- **Largest segments**
- Full name
- **Most recent**

---

Getting to your three sorting methods:

1. Sorting by Most recent brings the newest result to the top.
2. To get the largest segment match first, sort by Largest segments.
3. To my knowledge there is no way to specify to only show matches of segments over a certain length. However, to find all matches with segments over, for instance, 30 cM, by sorting by Largest segments brings these all to the top of the list. In my case, there are only 4 matches with segments longer than 30 cM, so that makes it easy.

Comment: Thank you I didn't see "shared DNA" drop-down box... very helpful!

Comment: @TJinBC MyHeritage has updated its filtering -- news here: https://blog.myheritage.com/2018/06/revolutionary-new-filtering-system-for-dna-matching/